# Ubuntu Wireless not working 14.04 XPS 13 9343

Tags: wireless, dell

I had wireless working, ran some DELL updates and now I do not. How can I troubleshoot? I have a USB dongle and now that doesn't even work. What could be the root cause of this?

Comment: Regarding the internal wireless adapter please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity, what kind of Dell update did you run ?

To fix the WiFi on Ubuntu 14.04 download the following packages :

1. [bcmwl-kernel-source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source)
2. [dkms](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/dkms)
3. [fakeroot](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/fakeroot)
4. [libfakeroot](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libfakeroot)

Install them :

```
sudo dpkg -i libfakeroot*.deb
sudo dpkg -i fakeroot*.deb
sudo dpkg -i dkms*.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl-kernel-source*.deb
```

Reboot your computer and the WiFi should work properly.

Comment: I have dell xps 13. I downloaded the packages. I installed them, but wireless still does not work.

Comment: I tried installing these, but am getting dependency errors for both dkms and bcmwl